Data Extension Inventory script - not loading into the DE
I have this SSJS/WSProxy script that should extract all DEs over 2 years old from create date & load the DE info into "DE_Inventory_list" DE. No errors but would not load the list of DEs into the "DE_Inventory_list". Partially sourced snippet from: https://gortonington.com/sfmc-data-extension-inventory-take-2/
Here is my "DE_Inventory_list" DE screenshot:

<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("Core","1");

try {
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var custKey = "DE_Inventory_list";
    var queryAllAccounts = true;
    var MidBuDE = "BusinessUnit";
    var cohort = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    var deArr = get_de_list();
    
     for (var a = 0; a < deArr.length; a++) {
        var deData = deArr[a].Results;
                
         for (var e = 0; e < deData.length; e++) {
            var name = deData[e].Name;
            var buID = deData[e].Client.ID;
            var dt = new Date();
            var date_end = addDate(dt, -2, 'years');
            var mod_date = deData[e].ModifiedDate;
            var create_date = deData[e].CreatedDate;
            var isSendable = deData[e].IsSendable;
            var objectID = deData[e].ObjectID;
            var sendableDEField = deData[e].SendableDataExtensionField.Name;
            
            if ((create_date < date_end) && (isSendable == true) && (sendableDEField == 'ID_Subscriber')) {
                var customerkey = deData[e].CustomerKey;
                var desc = deData[e].Description;
                var v_CreatedDate = deData[e].CreatedDate;
                var v_ModifiedDate = deData[e].ModifiedDate;
                var nameArr = ["Name", "Description", "IsSendable", "CreatedDate", "ModifiedDate", "ObjectID"];
                var valueArr = [name, desc, isSendable, v_CreatedDate, v_ModifiedDate, objectID];
                var upsertDeInfo = Platform.Function.UpsertData(custKey, ["MID", "CustomerKey"], [buID, customerkey], nameArr, valueArr);

            } //End If
        }  //End for Loop # 2
    }  //End for Loop # 1 

//extract DE function
function get_de_list() {
     var cols = ["ObjectID","CustomerKey","Name","CreatedDate","ModifiedDate","Client.ID"
               ,"Description","IsSendable","SendableDataExtensionField.Name", "SendableSubscriberField.Name"];
  
//Query Affiliated  BUsiness Unit (143) in "BusinessUnit" data extensions
  var BuDE = DataExtension.Init(MidBuDE);
  var buMID;
  var buMID_Arr = [];
  
  //var data = BuDE.Rows.Retrieve();
     var row_filter = { Property:"COHORT"
                      , SimpleOperator: "IN"   //"equals"
                     , Value:cohort           //Cohort = 1,2,3 ...   //To be decided by SFMC Delete Focus group
                    };     

  var row_data = BuDE.Rows.Retrieve(row_filter);  //Has Cohort Filter 
//var row_data = BuDE.Rows.Retrieve();  //No Filter

  var end = row_data.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < end; i++) {       //loop through BUsinessUnit DE rows  
      var buMID = row_data[i]['MID'];
      buMID_Arr.push(buMID)
  }
      //Include ONLY UMF Affiliated BUs 
      var filter = {Property: "Client.ID"
                    , SimpleOperator:  "IN"  //"equals"
                    , Value: buMID_Arr      //buMID_Arr      //KIN : 6358753  //UMF: 6287172   //UMF-Dev : 6262040 
                 }

    var reqID = null
    var moreData = true;
    var desc = [];

    while(moreData) {
      moreData = false;
      var data = reqID == null ? prox.retrieve("DataExtension", cols, filter, queryAllAccounts): prox.getNextBatch("DataExtension", reqID); //retrieve entire BUs DEs
      if(data != null) {
        moreData = data.HasMoreRows;
        reqID = data.RequestID;
        if(data && data.Results) {
          desc.push(data);
        }
      }
    }
 return desc;
} //End get_de_list function

function addDate(dt, amount, dateType) {
    switch (dateType) {
    case 'days':
      return dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + amount) && dt;
    case 'weeks':
      return dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + (7 * amount)) && dt;
    case 'months':
      return dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() + amount) && dt;
    case 'years':
      return dt.setFullYear( dt.getFullYear() + amount) && dt;
     }
  }//addDate Fuction 

} //End Try 
catch (e) {
        Write("Error occurred: " + Stringify(e)); // Debugging output
    } //End Catch
</script>


Clarification: Script targets to pull DEs only those MID listed in "BusinessUnit" DE

I figured out that the issue was that the  if ((create_date < date_end) && (isSendable == true) && (sendableDEField == 'ID_Subscriber')) { part of my code was not working, and in particular create_date < date_end. I added Write('xxx') to debug as I suspect that might be the issue, and I was correct that I saw an error message complaining about the Date_end not having correct "Month".
My workaround: skip the date restriction logic and basically load all into a Staging DE and then write SQL to do date restriction (which I'm more comfortable) and load the final data into the "DE_Inventory_list".
